# Plug-in org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted was unable to load class

Tags: m2eclipse

Version: 3.8.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201610040743
Platform: Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)
This is my version
Plug-in org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted was unable to load class org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard

Answer (score 1):

It can depends on your OS, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103148/6309)

> The 'WelcomeDashboard' uses JavaFX which requires Java 1.8 and GTK2 on unix systems. Eclipse 4.4 runs with GTK3 by default.

As mentioned in [issue 252](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/252#issuecomment-373442104),

> The error log probably contains more detailed information and/or other errors that might help determine why this class could not be loaded. You can use menu "`Window >> Show View >> Other >> Error Log`" to show the error log.
>
> Maybe something indicative of problems activating bundles. The reason the class can't be found is probably because some bundle requirement aren't satisfied on startup.
>
> you could also try to open a console view, switch to the Host OSGI Console, and try a > `diag org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted` to see if there is a problem with that bundle (not resolved for any reason, for example).

As in:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35578715/37673974-aeb18454-2c97-11e8-8c5d-453d00ee980c.png]

You would see typically:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35578715/37656306-ade8428a-2c6d-11e8-9507-3c708d1a8dc4.png]

The same issue adds:

> You can use the 'Old Dashboard' as a workaround. It offers the same functionality as the one that for still unknown reason isn't work for you. To switch to the old dashboard do as follows:
>
> Go to Menu "`Window >> Preferences`".
> Search for 'dashboard'. Then select 'Use Old Dashboard' as in the screenshot below.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1002156/37665597-d6518c84-2c1a-11e8-884c-82a7893a5d2b.png]

> Then click the '`Apply and Close`' button to save the changed setting.

Then close the 'new dashboard' (that is the view in your screenshot that has the error in it).

> Now you can reopen the dashboard by clicking on the Dashboard icon in the toolbar.   I.e. this one:
> [image: open-dashboard-button: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1002156/37665759-32419854-2c1b-11e8-8278-ae1bf5ef2a63.png]